# Where to get non-static object to call his method?

Tags: java, class, oop, non-static

Very newbie Q about JavaFX classes. Main is a main starting class in JavaFX, and it has no constructor (I dont know why)

**Main.java**

```
class Main extends Application {
   Log  log;   // class, not shown here
   Work work;
   @Override
   public void start() // entry point
   {
      log  = new Log("main.log"); // opens log file, need to be non-static
      work = new Work();
   }
}
```

**Work.java**

```
class Work{
     public Work() // constructor
    {
       Main.log.write("Making work object");  // error
       // What is the right method to call one non-static class from another ???
    }
```

Comment: is this a `JavaFX Application` class ?

Comment: When you call `Main.log`, `log` needs to be static. You need to create an instance of Main and then call log using it.

Comment: Yes this is JavaFX app, NetBean IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
class Main extends Application {
   public static Log  log = new Log("main.log");   // class, not shown here
   Work work;
   public start() // entry point
   {
       work = new Work();
   }
}
```

then only you can use

```
Main.log.write("Making work object");
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass log to the Work instance.

```
class Main extends Application {
   Log  log;   // class, not shown here
   Work work;
   public start() // entry point
   {
      log  = new Log("main.log"); // opens log file, need to be non-static
      work = new Work(log);
   }
}
```

== Work.java ==

```
class Work{
    Log  log;
    public Work(Log log) // constructor
    {
       this.log = log;
       log.write("Making work object");           
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `Log` needs to be `public` and `static`.

Only when something is declared `public` can you access it in another class (without inheritance, I mean)

and

Only when something is declared `static` can you refer to it as `Classname.VariableName`

```
class Main extends Application {
   public static Log  log; // see the change ?   
   ...
   public void start() // this needed a return type
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Log cant be static. It needs constructor, to open log file.

Comment: @xoid `static` objects can very well be initialized. ;)